# PDFTK to fill form

Tags: forms, pdf, fill, pdftk

I found this code

```
function createFDF($file,$info){
$data="%FDF-1.2\n%âãÏÓ\n1 0 obj\n<< \n/FDF << /Fields [ ";
foreach($info as $field => $val){
if(is_array($val)){
$data.='<</T('.$field.')/V[';
foreach($val as $opt)
$data.='('.trim($opt).')';
$data.=']>>';
}else{
$data.='<</T('.$field.')/V('.trim($val).')>>';
}
}
$data.="] \n/F (".$file.") /ID [ <".md5(time()).">\n] >>".
" \n>> \nendobj\ntrailer\n".
"<<\n/Root 1 0 R \n\n>>\n%%EOF\n";
return $data;
}



$fileName = "Template_PDF.pdf";
$fdf_file = "temporary.fdf";
$result_file = "Result.pdf";
$arr['a_variable'] = 'value or a variable';


$fdf_data = createFDF($fileName, $arr);


if($fp=fopen($fdf_file,'w'))
{
    fwrite($fp,$fdf_data,strlen($fdf_data));
}
else
{
    echo 'Unable to create file: '.$fdf_file.'<br>';
}
fclose($fp);
exec("pdftk ".$fileName." fill_form ".$fdf_file." output ".$result_file );
```

in this page [Input PDF format for PDFTK form fill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171124/input-pdf-format-for-pdftk-form-fill)

It work correctly but don't return result.php file because I haven't PDFTK locally or on my site.
Where I can find it and how I can install it ?

Comment: Stack Snippets are for _runnable_ HTML/JavaScript/CSS code snippets.

Comment: I resolved the problem with [FPDF / FPDM](http://www.fpdf.org/)